# Issue with Universal Forwarder forwarding logs to index

Tags: splunk

I have installed splunk UF on windows . I have one static log file in system (json)  and that need to be monitored.   I have configure this in inputs.conf file.
I see only system/application and security logs being sent to indexer whereas the static log file is not seen.

```
I ran "splunk list inputstatus" and checked, 

C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\test\test.json
file position = 75256
file size = 75256
percent = 100.00
type = finished reading
```

So, this means the file is being read properly.

What can be the issue that I dont see test.json logs at splunk side ? I tried checking index=_internal at indexer but not able to figure out what is causing issue, I checked few blogs on Internet as well. Can anyone please help on this.

`inputs.conf` stanza:

```
[monitor://C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\data test\test.json]
disabled = 0 
index = test_index 
sourcetype = test_data
```

Comment: Please show the inputs.conf stanza for the static file.  Please also show the SPL used to search for data from that file.

Comment: Additionally, check the %SPLUNK_HOME%\var\log\splunk\splunkd.log file on the UF.

Comment: @RichG:        This is my stanza in inputs.conf file :

[monitor://C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\data test\test.json]
disabled = 0
index = test_index
sourcetype = test_data

I dont see any error in splunkd.log file.

Comment: Is the monitor name (`C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\data test\test.json`) correct?  What query are you using to find data?

Comment: @RichG - I was able to log forwarded very much later. There was some delaying issue. Thanks for your response and help :) Appreciated

Comment: What did you change that data started forwarding?